# Unable to move next form after select value from comboBox

Tags: c#

I am unable to move next form after selecting combobox value..
My Button click is

```
namespace Combobox
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          if(combo.SelectedItem.ToString()=="Yes Bank")
          {
                Emp newForm = new Emp();
                newForm.Show();
                this.Hide();
          }
          else if (combo.SelectedItem.ToString()=="Bitsforge")
          {
                Temp newForm = new Temp();
                newForm.Show();
                this.Hide();
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: See that Emp and Temp are in same namespace

Comment: I changed name...even though not working

Comment: There's too little information to help you right now. How does the `Emp` and `Temp` forms look like? What do you mean by "I am unable to move next form after selecting combobox value"? Is it showing after the click and then you can't move it?

Comment: Are Emp and Temp inheriting Form? If so, where are their class definition? I hope it is in the same name space(ComboBox).Are you clicking on button after selecting combobox value? Are you sure the combobox value is selected? Have you used debugger yet?

Comment: @sukhoi ..yes after click i cant move to next form...Emp and Temp are normal two windows forms..if i select "Yes Bank" and clicked, Emp form should be open and if i select "Bitsforge" and clicked, Temp form should be open

Comment: @Nilay Vishwakarma..Value is visible in comboBox after select a value i am clicking GO button But it Not working

Comment: Have tried putting breakpoint after the if to see if it even gets there? A lot of things can be solved just by debugging. Maybe you have some typo there...

Comment: try using combobox.SelectedIndexChanged event, it is literally impossible to resolve this issue with the limited info

Comment: @Nilay Vishwakarma.for example..assume that i have a login form ,before enter username and password i should select User type(Employee,manager etc..) from combo box.if i didint select any value from combo box i cant enter to login form...how can we write code for this???

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your problem: Form1 has ComboBox and Button. After selecting the proper value in ComboBox and clicking on the button, Form2 is showing up. It works, so there's definitely something wrong with your code in the part not shown in this question. Also, maybe it's a little offtopic, but make sure that if you use `Show()/Hide()` methods you close the application after closing another form (you can use `Closing` event for this, just put there something like `Application.Exit()`). It would be better to use `ShowDialog(newForm)` instead, but maybe it doesn't fit into your idea.

Comment: @sukhoi191..can u send me the code

Comment: @SemilSebastian Just create new Windows Forms Application, then add new form, put `ComboBox` and `Button` on the first one, add something to `ComboBox` like `comboBox1.Items.Add("Yes"); comboBox1.Items.Add("No");` and in the Button-click event do the same as in your question, with `Show()` and `Hide()` methods. That's how I get this problem, if I misunderstood anything please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

See the following snippet. I don't observe any issue in this sample:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ComboBox
{
public class Temp : Form
{
    public Temp()
    {
        this.Text = "Bitsforge";
    }
}
public class Emp : Form
{
    public Emp()
    {
        this.Text = "Yes Bank";
    }
}
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (combo.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Yes Bank")
        {
            Emp newForm = new Emp();
            newForm.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
        else if (combo.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Bitsforge")
        {
            Temp newForm = new Temp();
            newForm.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

}

You may download the sample application from : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4OTJAUnKQn4N24za205cWc0cms/edit?usp=sharing